# Using AngularJS 2 in Spring MVC 4.0.0 RELEASE

Tags: spring-mvc, angular, typescript, integrate

Has someone experiences integrate AngularJS 2 in Spring MVC? What libraries you add to your web-app? How we can run Typescript in Spring? Project's structure? I tried to find from here but nothing found can help me. Basically i've finished building Rest API, configure security for my web app. Now i want to use AngularJS 2 in client side to handle user's request and response.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I would suggest to keep your Spring RestAPI decoupled from the Angular2 application. Both can be different projects that communicate using XHR requests.

Comment: Thanks bro! If i understand correctly, you mean i create another Spring project? Then use the first one as a web service? But we still need install Typescript and how can i run it inside Tomcat?

Comment: You don't need to create a Spring project for Angular2 application. It will be a stand alone Angular2 application. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html

Comment: Thanks bro! I research it right now.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2015/08/19/migrating-a-spring-web-mvc-application-from-jsp-to-angularjs This is Angluar Js 1, but may help